# GWT Canvas: how to change line color

Tags: gwt, canvas, colors

Since the canvas drawing in GWT has been all over the map, let me be explicit and say I'm using this:

```
import com.google.gwt.canvas.client.Canvas;
```

The problem is that if I draw a black line and then change to red, the first line is changed to red also.

```
// draw line in black
 context.moveTo(xScale(-0.5), yScale(0.0));
 context.lineTo(xScale(15.0), yScale(0.0));
 context.stroke();

 // change to red
 context.setStrokeStyle(CssColor.make(255,0,0));


 context.moveTo(xScale(0.0), yScale(20.0));
 context.lineTo(xScale(0.0), yScale(-20.0));
 context.stroke();

 // both lines appear in red
```

What is the correct method for changing pen color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `context.beginPath()` before each new shape/line with different color should fix your problem.

```
// draw line in black
 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(xScale(-0.5), yScale(0.0));
 context.lineTo(xScale(15.0), yScale(0.0));
 context.stroke();

 context.beginPath();
 // change to red
 context.setStrokeStyle(CssColor.make(255,0,0));

 context.moveTo(xScale(0.0), yScale(20.0));
 context.lineTo(xScale(0.0), yScale(-20.0));
 context.stroke();

 // both lines appear in red
```

Basically beginPath() pushed the state